# Resolving "Framework not found FBLPromises" Error when Building iOS and Mac App with CocoaPods and Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

I'm using CocoaPods to include Firebase and other dependencies in my iOS project. It seems that Firebase cannot be used on Mac. When building an app that supports both iOS and Mac, I encounter an error specifically on the Mac version saying 'Framework not found FBLPromises.' How can I resolve this? I believe disabling CocoaPods for the Mac version or excluding Firebase might solve the issue, but I'm unsure how to do it. I tried filtering the Pods_hoge.framework for iOS only, but it didn't resolve the problem.